# Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm working on a simple app that requires me to submit a form. I created two models.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email

  has_many :item
end
```

**item.rb**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id

  belongs_to :user
end
```

Instead of creating a user using the **user form view**, I'm trying to create the user using the **item form view**.

**items/_form.html.haml**

```
= nested_form_for @item do |form|

  = form.fields_for :user do |builder|
    = builder.text_field :email

  = form.submit "Save"
```

Did I miss something here? I'm using nested_form_for btw. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my problem.

I updated my items_controller.rb

```
def new
  @item = Item.new
  @item.user = User.new # I added this line.
end
```

Then I updated the item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_attributes

  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

Comment: What if you want to create an item for an existing user?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
attr_accessible :email :user
```

Comment: to make nested forms work, unless there's some magic going on I don't know about, you should add:

accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

check details here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for

to your item model.

Comment: @trueunlessfalse I tried to include that but it hides the email field in the view.

Comment: Your nested form now tries to display @item.user, which in your case seems to be nil - thus it's not displaying anything at all.

You can make sure you're item has a built user, e.g. by adding:

  = form.fields_for (@item.user || @item.user.build)

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user      # <--- This should help

  belongs_to :user
end 

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email

  has_many :items                          # <--- Typofix
end
```