# Rails Engage! Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm working on installing [Engage!](http://engagecsm.com/)

I followed the installation instructions found here: http://engagecsm.com/readme

Installation steps I did:

1. Add Engage! to the application's Gemfile: gem 'engagecsm'.
2. Install it: bundle install.
3. Run the generator: rails generate engage User.
4. Run the migrations: rake db:migrate.

Now, I can go to localhost:3000/engage

[image: Picture of the results of doing "rake routes". It displays "engage /engage Engage::Engine]

This is what shows up:

[image: This is a picture of the Engage! forum, where I have entered data to be used in created a new topic. THere is a "Create Topic" submit button in the bottom right that I click to get the error in the rails server console.]

Now, when I hit "Create Topic", nothing happens on the site. I look at my rails server console and I see this: (Easier to view here https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKBER.png, full stack trace found at the bottom)

[image: Started POST "/engage/topics" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-19 19:48:26 -0700 Processing by Engage::TopicsController#create as JS Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"aRKQAwMsnc1DJJ62S6bb7EkhFkzuCDtNL0kV756LIP4=", "topic"=>{"style"=>"question", "title"=>"ww", "message"=>"www", "follow"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Topic"} User Load (0.3ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1 Engage::UserProfile Load (0.4ms) SELECT "engage_user_profiles".* FROM "engage_user_profiles" WHERE "engage_user_profiles"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1 (0.1ms) begin transaction Engage::UserProfile Load (0.3ms) SELECT "engage_user_profiles".* FROM "engage_user_profiles" INNER JOIN "users" ON "engage_user_profiles"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1 SQL (1.2ms) INSERT INTO "engage_topics" ("comments_count", "created_at", "followers_count", "message", "private", "status", "string", "style", "title", "updated_at", "user_id", "votes_count") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [["comments_count", 0], ["created_at", Sun, 20 Jan 2013 02:48:26 UTC +00:00], ["followers_count", 0], ["message", "www"], ["private", false], ["status", "pending"], ["string", nil], ["style", "question"], ["title", "ww"], ["updated_at", Sun, 20 Jan 2013 02:48:26 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1], ["votes_count", 0]] Engage::Following Load (0.3ms) SELECT "engage_followings".* FROM "engage_followings" WHERE "engage_followings"."topic_id" = 7 AND "engage_followings"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1 User Load (0.2ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1 Binary data inserted for <code>string</code> type on column <code>token</code> SQL (0.9ms) INSERT INTO "engage_followings" ("created_at", "token", "topic_id", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [["created_at", Sun, 20 Jan 2013 02:48:26 UTC +00:00], ["token", "5813db34aaedfa6226cf77b7a17d5dfbcf8d4560"], ["topic_id", 7], ["updated_at", Sun, 20 Jan 2013 02:48:26 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1]] Engage::Topic Load (0.2ms) SELECT "engage_topics".* FROM "engage_topics" WHERE "engage_topics"."id" = 7 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1 SQL (0.8ms) UPDATE "engage_topics" SET "followers_count" = COALESCE("followers_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "engage_topics"."id" IN (SELECT "engage_topics"."id" FROM "engage_topics" WHERE "engage_topics"."id" = 7 ORDER BY created_at DESC) (3.8ms) commit transaction (0.1ms) begin transaction (0.1ms) rollback transaction Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 71msActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user): activemodel (3.2.11) lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:48:in <code>process_removed_attributes' activemodel (3.2.11) lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:20:in</code>debug_protected_attribute_removal' activemodel (3.2.11) lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:12:in `sanitize']

So I start googling, and I see things like this:

- [Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447937/cant-mass-assign-protected-attributes-user)
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment

I already added attr_accessible :user to my User model, but that didn't work.

Here's my User model:

[image: class User < ActiveRecord::Base include Engage::Extensions::User has_many :resources has_many :resource_views, :class_name => 'UserResourceView' has_many :viewed_resources, :through => :resource_views, :source => :resource has_many :evaluations, class_name: "RSEvaluation", as: :source has_reputation :votes, source: {reputation: :votes, of: :resources}, aggregated_by: :sum has_reputation :karma, :source => { :reputation => :votes, :of => :resources } def voted_for?(resource) evaluations.where(target_type: resource.class, target_id: resource.id).present? end def recently_viewed_resources viewed_resources.order('user_resource_views.created_at DESC') end # Include default devise modules. Others available are: # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model attr_accessible :user_id, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me # attr_accessible :title, :body end]

Also, I can't see how I have access to Engage models and such, see here's my directory:

[image: List of my directory: Controllers, Helpers, Models and Views. None of which is Engage specific. I couldn't find where Engage's controllers and such was. It is in the gem.]

Does anyone know how to fix this? If you want any other information, please tell me and I'll provide screenshots.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT #1 - Adding application controller picture and full stack trace

This is the only place I can see anything with Engage! in controllers (I don't have a User controller at this time)

[image: application_controller.rb file. class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base include Engage::Extensions::Helpers protect_from_forgery end]

Here's the full stack trace:

[image: Started POST "/engage/topics" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-19 19:48:26 -0700 Processing by Engage::TopicsController#create as JS Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"aRKQAwMsnc1DJJ62S6bb7EkhFkzuCDtNL0kV756LIP4=", "topic"=>{"style"=>"question", "title"=>"ww", "message"=>"www", "follow"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Topic"} User Load (0.3ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1 Engage::UserProfile Load (0.4ms) SELECT "engage_user_profiles".* FROM "engage_user_profiles" WHERE "engage_user_profiles"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1 (0.1ms) begin transaction Engage::UserProfile Load (0.3ms) SELECT "engage_user_profiles".* FROM "engage_user_profiles" INNER JOIN "users" ON "engage_user_profiles"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1 SQL (1.2ms) INSERT INTO "engage_topics" ("comments_count", "created_at", "followers_count", "message", "private", "status", "string", "style", "title", "updated_at", "user_id", "votes_count") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [["comments_count", 0], ["created_at", Sun, 20 Jan 2013 02:48:26 UTC +00:00], ["followers_count", 0], ["message", "www"], ["private", false], ["status", "pending"], ["string", nil], ["style", "question"], ["title", "ww"], ["updated_at", Sun, 20 Jan 2013 02:48:26 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1], ["votes_count", 0]] Engage::Following Load (0.3ms) SELECT "engage_followings".* FROM "engage_followings" WHERE "engage_followings"."topic_id" = 7 AND "engage_followings"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1 User Load (0.2ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1 Binary data inserted for <code>string</code> type on column <code>token</code> SQL (0.9ms) INSERT INTO "engage_followings" ("created_at", "token", "topic_id", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [["created_at", Sun, 20 Jan 2013 02:48:26 UTC +00:00], ["token", "5813db34aaedfa6226cf77b7a17d5dfbcf8d4560"], ["topic_id", 7], ["updated_at", Sun, 20 Jan 2013 02:48:26 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1]] Engage::Topic Load (0.2ms) SELECT "engage_topics".* FROM "engage_topics" WHERE "engage_topics"."id" = 7 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1 SQL (0.8ms) UPDATE "engage_topics" SET "followers_count" = COALESCE("followers_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "engage_topics"."id" IN (SELECT "engage_topics"."id" FROM "engage_topics" WHERE "engage_topics"."id" = 7 ORDER BY created_at DESC) (3.8ms) commit transaction (0.1ms) begin transaction (0.1ms) rollback transaction Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 71ms]
[image: SQL (0.9ms) INSERT INTO "engage_followings" ("created_at", "token", "topic_id", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [["created_at", Sun, 20 Jan 2013 02:48:26 UTC +00:00], ["token", "5813db34aaedfa6226cf77b7a17d5dfbcf8d4560"], ["topic_id", 7], ["updated_at", Sun, 20 Jan 2013 02:48:26 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1]] Engage::Topic Load (0.2ms) SELECT "engage_topics".* FROM "engage_topics" WHERE "engage_topics"."id" = 7 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1 SQL (0.8ms) UPDATE "engage_topics" SET "followers_count" = COALESCE("followers_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "engage_topics"."id" IN (SELECT "engage_topics"."id" FROM "engage_topics" WHERE "engage_topics"."id" = 7 ORDER BY created_at DESC) (3.8ms) commit transaction (0.1ms) begin transaction (0.1ms) rollback transaction Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 71ms ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user): activemodel (3.2.11) lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:48:in <code>process_removed_attributes' activemodel (3.2.11) lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:20:in</code>debug_protected_attribute_removal' activemodel (3.2.11) lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:12:in <code>sanitize' activemodel (3.2.11) lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:230:in</code>sanitize_for_mass_assignment' activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:75:in <code>assign_attributes' activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/base.rb:497:in</code>initialize' activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:183:in <code>new' activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:183:in</code>build_association' activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:233:in <code>build_record' activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:434:in</code>block in create_record' activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:149:in <code>block in transaction' activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in</code>transaction' activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in <code>transaction' activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:148:in</code>transaction' activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:433:in <code>create_record' activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:119:in</code>create' activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:46:in <code>create' engagecsm (1.0.8) app/controllers/engage/topics_controller.rb:46:in</code>create' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in <code>send_action' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in</code>process_action' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in <code>process_action' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in</code>block in process_action' activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:426:in `block in _run__2010401100414174750__process_action__2035169522325419882__callbacks']

[image: activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in <code>block in _conditional_callback_around_4085' activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:326:in</code>around' activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:310:in <code>_callback_around_127' activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:214:in</code>_conditional_callback_around_4085' activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in <code>_run__2010401100414174750__process_action__2035169522325419882__callbacks' activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in</code>__run_callback' activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in <code>_run_process_action_callbacks' activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in</code>run_callbacks' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in <code>process_action' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in</code>process_action' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in <code>block in process_action' activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in</code>block in instrument' activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in <code>instrument' activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in</code>instrument' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in <code>process_action' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in</code>process_action' activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in <code>process_action' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in</code>process' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in <code>process' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in</code>dispatch' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in <code>dispatch' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in</code>block in action' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in <code>call' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in</code>dispatch' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in <code>call' journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in</code>block in call' journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in <code>each' journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in</code>call' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in <code>call' railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in</code>call' railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in <code>method_missing' journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in</code>block in call' journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in <code>each' journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in</code>call'actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in <code>call' warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in</code>block in call' warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in <code>catch' warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in</code>call' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in <code>call' rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in</code>call' rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in <code>call' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in</code>call' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call']

[image: actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in <code>call' rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in</code>context' rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in <code>call' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in</code>call' activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in <code>call' activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in</code>call' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in <code>block in call' activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in</code>_run__4377122496359715927__call__4128007891844716680__callbacks' activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in <code>__run_callback' activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in</code>_run_call_callbacks' activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in <code>run_callbacks' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in</code>call' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in <code>call' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in</code>call' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in <code>call' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in</code>call' railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in <code>call_app' railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in</code>block in call' activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in <code>tagged' railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in</code>call' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in <code>call' rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in</code>call' rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in <code>call' activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in</code>call' rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in <code>call' actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in</code>call' railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in <code>call' railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in</code>call' rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in <code>call' railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in</code>call' rack (1.4.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in <code>service' /Users/johndoe/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327-perf/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in</code>service' /Users/johndoe/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327-perf/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in <code>run' /Users/johndoe/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327-perf/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in</code>block in start_thread']

EDIT #2 - Add engage environment:

Also, we have Devise (and OmniAuth I believe...) installed. Therefore, we have "current_user", but I don't know if we have a "username" or "email" method, unless that comes standard with Devise or something
[image: This is the engage.rb file. Engage.configure do |config| config.layout = 'application' config.user_model = 'User' config.mailer_sender = 'engage@knowledgethief.com' config.internal_authentication = false config.current_user_method = Proc.new { current_user } config.login_link = { :path => :new_user_session_path, :opts => { :remote => true } } config.username_method = Proc.new { username } config.email_method = Proc.new { email } end]

EDIT #3 - As Geoff suggested, I looked at line 46 of the topics_controller. That line is the following:

@topic.votes.create(:user => engage_current_user)

Comment: You posted a lot of helpful info, but can you include the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: For sure! I just added the full stack trace. If there's anything other information I can give to be useful, please let me know! I also added the engage.rb environment file, which may be useful, I'm not sure.

Comment: Do not post images of text, instead copy-and-paste the actual text. Images of text are not easily parseable, searchable, or accessible.

Comment: You present a valid point. I understand the motivation behind your words. However, the text in these pictures would generally dilute the focus of this question. For example, I would not be aiding the search algorithm by having this question dilute a query for "rails reputation system", which would be the result of adding my User Model's text. I succinctly summed up the important text in my title: "Rails Engage! Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user)". Additionally, I have found seemingly endless walls of text quickly erode a user's motivation to read and provide valuable answers.

Comment: @FoolishChap What if I was blind and wanted to answer your question? Or thought your question might solve my problem but can’t actual figure out what you did?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Added full text of every picture to it's description in the code behind in hopes of creating a more valuable resource for our blind community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's one of Engage! developers here. I can see there are two problems with Engage! described above.

We have found the solution to the first (the one that you have solved with `attr_accessible :user`), so expect a Rubygems update soon.

The second (the fact that topics are not actually displayed on the index page) is connected with the changes in the cancan gem. We still have to figure out the best way to approach this, but a quick workaround is to lock the cancan version in the Gemfile as follows: `gem 'cancan', '1.6.7'`.

We will let you know when the updates addressing these issues will be available at Rubygems.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information given, I'm afraid I can't tell what's going on but I can help give a little explanation of the error you're getting.

The last non-library line in your trace is:

engagecsm (1.0.8) app/controllers/engage/topics_controller.rb:46: in `create'

This code is probably in your default gem path. Probably either `/usr/lib/ruby/gems` or `/home/user_name/.gem/ruby` if you're on *nix.

Sometime in the processing of that line of code, it hit a Mass-assignment security error.

It might help you to look at that line of code to see which model it's hitting. *DO NOT* post that line of code here. The licence for Engage! does not appear to be one of the standard open source ones and you may be in violation of the license if you post here. I may very well be wrong, but better safe than sorry.

There are two variable which can trip you up with Mass-assignment security. They are the attribute and the role. Adding `attr_accessible :user` to the appropriate Model will help only if they are using the default role. If they are using the `:admin` role, then you need to add `attr_accessible :user, as: :admin`. I don't think your `User` model has an attribute of `:user` so it probably needs to be added somewhere else.

If I had to guess what you did wrong, I think you might have followed the security guide here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

In that guide, they suggest setting your config to whitelist everything by default.

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

If you did this and Engage! wasn't written with MassAssignment support, that would explain the error you're seeing.

Sorry I can't explain your issue with any certainty, but I hope it helps nonetheless.

Comment: I appreciate your post Geoff. I am following your advice, investigating the code within the engage gem. I'll report back when I have more information. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, this helped a lot. I got unstuck in my problem solving! I still haven't figured it out, but look at line 46: @topic.votes.create(:user => engage_current_user)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your [image: stack trace] your problem is in the topices_controller - therefore likely to mean that you need to add `:user_id` to the `attr_accessible` in the `Engage/Topic` model.

Comment: This was close, and led me to get through this error. Thank you! It turned out that I needed to add "attr_accessible :user" to Engage/Vote model.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the following line to Engage/Vote Model

```
attr_accessible :user
```

Now it will say "Topic successfully created."

However, I can't see the topics listed. However, I believe I'm done with this portion of the problem. I am able to see the topic when I go to

```
http://localhost:3000/engage/topics/1
```