# How can I add a line to a proprietary ruby gem so it will work correctly on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I need to add

```
attr_accessible :user
```

To the Vote model of the engagecsm gem.

See this question for why I need to do this (skip to the answer): [Rails Engage! Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421250/rails-engage-error-cant-mass-assign-protected-attributes-user)

Now, usually I would just fork this on github and add the line, but there's not a github for it, plus I think it may be against the rules to put it out to the public or something. Anyways, so I have just been adding the gem on the gemfile as noted here: https://rubygems.org/gems/engagecsm

I have added that line to my local install of engagecsm by opening the gem on my local computer and typing in that line. However, I want this to work on Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `config/application.rb`:

```
# run before each request in dev, or during initialization in test & prod
config.to_prepare do
  # re-open the `Vote` class so we can make some changes
  Vote.class_exec do
    # the custom changes
    attr_accessible :user
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `lib` folder, create a file (my recommendation would be `lib/ext/engagecms/vote.rb`), and put the following:

```
require 'engagecms' #make this the correct require for the gem, the goal is to force the gem to load before your code

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base # you'll need to make this declaration equal the engage one
  attr_accessible :user
end
```

This is monkey patching the code, so it might break in the future due to upgrades.

A better long term strategy would be to create a wrapper that converts `Vote.create(params[:vote])` (with `params[:vote]` having your `user` attribute) to

```
user = params[:vote].delete(:user)

Vote.create(params[:vote]) do |v|
  v.user = user
end
```

This technique allows you to act as if it is accessible, but avoids the monkey patch, which is not a best practice due to the risk of breakage and conflicts.